# Evolution script not created automatically in play 2.3.6 java jpa

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I am trying the to create my data base in mysql with jpa in play 2.3.6 but the evolutions script is not created.

My **build.sbt**

```
name := "myapp"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `myapp` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(javaJdbc ,
  javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),
  cache ,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.9.Final" )

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )
```

**application.conf**

```
# This is the main configuration file for the application.
# ~~~~~

# Secret key
# ~~~~~
# The secret key is used to secure cryptographics functions.
# If you deploy your application to several instances be sure to use the same key!
application.secret="%APPLICATION_SECRET%"

# The application languages
# ~~~~~
application.langs="en"

# Global object class
# ~~~~~
# Define the Global object class for this application.
# Default to Global in the root package.
# application.global=Global

# Router
# ~~~~~
# Define the Router object to use for this application.
# This router will be looked up first when the application is starting up,
# so make sure this is the entry point.
# Furthermore, it's assumed your route file is named properly.
# So for an application router like `my.application.Router`,
# you may need to define a router file `conf/my.application.routes`.
# Default to Routes in the root package (and conf/routes)
# application.router=my.application.Routes

# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"
db.default.user="user"
db.default.password="pass"
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit

# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
# evolutionplugin=disabled

# Logger
# ~~~~~
# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/),
# by providing an application-logger.xml file in the conf directory.

# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG
```

My model

```
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String name;

}
```

**conf/META-INF/persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

When I run the project it loads the index page as I have given, but it doesn't ask for apply this script part and also no script in generated name 1.sql

I can't seem to track the issue I found one of the similar issue but on that thread the solution was creating project again I have also tried that but that didn't work, also and I also can't find any solution of this.

I can't seem to get what the problem is, as there is no console error I rechecked everything from start but the same issue.

It would be a great help if anyone could point me to the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: can anybody give me some hint?